# How to write jstl instead of scriptlets?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
<%
    UserDetailsVO objUserDetailsVO = null;
   ArrayList arlUserDetailsVO = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("LSTUSERSDETAILS");
   String nonBifFlag = "";
   if(arlUserDetailsVO !=null){
   Iterator it = arlUserDetailsVO.iterator();
   String urlProfile="";
   while(it.hasNext()){
       objUserDetailsVO = (UserDetailsVO)it.next();
        urlProfile = "UserProfile.htm?userID="+objUserDetailsVO.getLogin_Ident()+"&internalID=111"+objUserDetailsVO.getInternalId();

 %>
```

Comment: is there any special reason for doing this?

Comment: @Harry yes. :) Its always better

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` from the [JSTL](http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/) are in your classpath (ie. your web project's `WEB-INF/lib` folder). A the top of your jsp page you will need:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

A literal translation of your code would look like this:

```
<c:set var="objUserDetailsVO" value="${null}"/>
<c:set var="arlUserDetailsVO" value="${requestScope['LSTUSERSDETAILS']}"/>
<c:set var="nonBifFlag" value=""/>
<c:if test="${not empty arlUserDetailsVO}">
    <c:set var="urlProfile" value="${null}"/>
    <c:forEach var="objUserDetailsVO" items="${arlUserDetailsVO}">
        <c:url var="urlProfile" value="UserProfile.htm">
            <c:param name="userID" value="${objUserDetailsVO.login_Ident}"/>
            <c:param name="internalID" value="111${objUserDetailsVO.internalId}"/>
        </c:url>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Although, considering tha you don't really need to set page/request attributes to `null` since they are already `null`, you could probably pare it down to this:

```
<c:set var="arlUserDetailsVO" value="${requestScope['LSTUSERSDETAILS']}"/>
<c:if test="${not empty arlUserDetailsVO}">
    <c:forEach var="objUserDetailsVO" items="${arlUserDetailsVO}">
        <c:url var="urlProfile" value="UserProfile.htm">
            <c:param name="userID" value="${objUserDetailsVO.login_Ident}"/>
            <c:param name="internalID" value="111${objUserDetailsVO.internalId}"/>
        </c:url>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Note that by using `<c:url>` to construct your url, your url params will now be correctly encoded, where as they are not being encoded in your java code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Try the core tags as well as bindings for the request etc., e.g. `<c:forEach>`, `<c:out>`, `<c:if>` ...

Here's a [short tutorial](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/722/)  (or if you can read German: [a German tutorial/reference](http://www.jsptutorial.org/content/jstl_core)).

Comment: I'm not sure how useful will be a tutorial in German to the OP  :)